# Problem with using opencv_GPU inside ROS

Tags: ros, cuda, gpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ALl,

I am very new into ROS. I wanted to use GPU support from OpenCv inside ROS platform. But I faced an error where it said ROS opencv is built without CUDA support. The I tried to build myself OpenCv(after downloading from OpenCv website) with CUDA support into the /usr/local . I wanted to test it with a simple code. But EVen though the version I downloaded and built is built with CUDA. My project somehow connects to the CV from ROS-fuerte and gives me an error as below.

OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in mallocPitch, file /tmp/buildd/**ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2**-0precise-20120908-1632/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp, line 749
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-0precise-20120908-1632/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp:749: error: (-216) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function mallocPitch

I have two questions. I am sure many of you will find it very simple problem. I am unable to understand how I can solve the below problems..

1. How can I use my local copy of OpenCv which I built with CUDA support ?
2. Is it possible to use it also in ROS ignoring the prebuilt openCv in ROS which is without CUDA support ?

regards,
Subhasis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47249/problem-with-using-opencv_gpu-inside-ros/) by [Subhasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3414/subhasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-04-23**:
can you use cuda with opencv in ROS? if you can ,would you share your Experience?my mail is goujiaolong@gmail.com   thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use your custom-built OpenCV instead of those provided by ROS.

Add this line to your .bashrc(or anywhere similarly where you set ROS environments):

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
```

Make sure your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is like this(`/usr/local` is the path prefix where you installed OpenCV):

```
$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/usr/local:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/catkin/cmake/Modules:/opt/ros/fuerte
```

Then add these lines to your CMakelists.txt:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2.4 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Start a new term and remove old build/* files, then `make` again. In this case CMake can find your installed OpenCV first.

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rookdroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4073/rookdroid/) on 2013-03-13**:
Hi K Chen, I've followed your steps however I am still having some issues with my program still being compiled with OPENCV2.4.2. I trying to debug this with no success. I checked the pkg that CMAKE is grabbing which is OPENCV2.3.1 which is what I want but when I compile and run I get 2.4.2 errors.

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-03-14**:
Which version of OpenCV do you want? ROS Fuerte provides OpenCV 2.4.x and if you want to use other versions or your custom built libs, refer to the instruction above and change the version xx in find_package(OpenCV xx)

**Comment by [746666288](https://answers.ros.org/users/4461/746666288/) on 2013-03-24**:
Hi K Chen,I want to know what should be changed in your sugestions with ROS-electric? thanks

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-03-31**:
I am not sure if this works for ROS Electric, but the `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is available for all current CMake versions, so you can give it a try. And if you have a rosdep in your manifest.xml, don't forget to remove it, or it can be confusing if you depends on two OpenCV version.

**Comment by [746666288](https://answers.ros.org/users/4461/746666288/) on 2013-03-31**:
thanks .your comments are very useful.haha

**Comment by [naveenT1010](https://answers.ros.org/users/30447/naveent1010/) on 2017-05-27**:
Hi, I am also trying to use GPU enabled OpenCV with ROS and I tried this method. I am able to compile the code but when starting the node with rosrun, it tries to get my kinetic opencv which is not GPU enabled and throws CUDA not enabled excetion. Any solutions for that?